# Connection timed out: connect, Eclipse juno + EGit

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, egit, eclipse-juno

I'm using Windows 7 with Eclipse Juno and EGit plugins
Whenever I try to Import > Project from Git, it always return eror message Connection timed out: connect.
[image: error message]

I try to import from git via ssh. with username/password

Did someone experienced this kind of issue?

Comment: Looks like either a proxy or firewall problem to me. Have you tried using the Git command line client?

Comment: I try using git command line client and TortoiseGit, both works fine

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue; for myself, it was a proxy-related issue. If you have a proxy, try the following.

First off, ensure you have your GIT configured for your proxy. Under your Eclipse preferences, venture to:

```
Team -> Git -> Configuration -> User Settings
```

Add the entry `http.proxy` with the value such as `http://<myip>:<myport>`.

Since GIT is using a proxy and my server is located in my local LAN, I had (for my setup) to add an exception in my Internet Options for my repository's host.

On a side note:

- I **did not** have to configure the `http.sslverify` GIT preference to get it to work.
- I **did not** have to manually alter any configurations under General -> Network Connections -> SSH2.
- I **did not** have to alter my GIT URL specifically tailored to an SSH connection (ie. I can use the string `<my user>@<host>:/opt/git/<repo>/` instead of `ssh://<my user>@<host>/opt/git/<repo>/`).